# Calculating the influence of changing volumes and values on a single average

Tags: analysis

I'll try and explain this well, and hopefully someone can help. Looking for a mathematically sound methodology (obviously).

I've got a sample population with a population size of $x$ and an average height of $y$

Within this population I have five separate sub-groups, all with varying population sizes, and varying average heights.

I sample this population in year 1 and then again in year 2. In year 2, the sizes of the five groups can vary from year 1, both in proportion of the whole, and in absolute number. The average height of each of the five groups can also go up or down in the second year.

I find that the average height $y$ of the whole group has increased by 10 cm between year 1 and year 2. What I would like to do is to assign an influence to the 10 different variables ($x$ and $y$ of each of the 5 sub-groups) to show the contribution of the change in each to the overall 10cm increase

[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Tba.png)

e.g. Group 1 $x$ +1cm $y$ +0cm
Group 2 $x$ +3cm $y$ -1cm
Group 3 $x$ -2cm $y$ -1cm
Group 4 $x$ +1cm $y$ +7cm
Group 5 $x$ +4cm $y$ -2cm
Total (hopefully) +10cm

Is there a formula I can use for each of these? I'll be setting it out in Excel if it helps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your math formatting. I know it's not necessary, but makes it easier to read in this case.

Comment: Could you explain what your variable $x$ measures? You say that $y$ measures height, but what is $x$?

Comment: To be clearer, we could define $y_n$ to be the change in average height for group $n$ between year 1 and year 2. So $y_1=0$, for example. Is this what you intended? How would you similarly define $x_n$?

Comment: Apologies, bit of a novice here! $x$ is the population size. What I'm interested in calculating is the proportion of the change in total $y$ ($y_n$) that is driven by the changes in $y$ ($y_n$) and $x$ ($x_n$) of the sub groups.

Comment: Have I explained it ok (apologies if not), or is it just more tricky than I'd hoped?

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I’ve a couple more queries though. When you say “Group 1 $x$ +1cm $y$ +0cm”, you imply that $x$ is also measured in cm. Do you mean just “+1” instead of “+1cm”? Also, do you have data for the actual sizes of each group in each of year 1 and year 2, instead of just the change in sizes? I think your question is answerable with this info!

Comment: The $x$ and $y$ shown for each of the groups in the table is the contribution that the change in that metric for sub-groups 1-5 has to the overall change in $y$ for the whole group, so how does doubling the population of one of the sub-groups affect the average height for the total group for example.

Comment: I've added a screenshot from Excel showing (hopefully) what I am trying to achieve. The yellow boxes are the ones I am looking to fill. They will all add up to 0.1m, as that is the total change in $y$ for the whole group (1.25m increasing to 1.35m). Some will be negative values. The table I originally posted is an example of what would be in those yellow cells (although just using examples rather than the data in the Excel sheet)

Answer (score 0):

Let me firstly formalise the notation for you.

Define $y_i^{(k)}$ to be the average height for group $i$ in year $k$. (For example, $y_3^{(2)}$ is the average height for group $3$ in year $2$.)

Similarly define $x_i^{(k)}$ to be the population size of group $i$ in year $k$.

Then define $y^{(k)}$ to be the overall average and $x^{(k)}$ to be the total population size in year $k$. So (as calculated on your spreadsheet) we have:

$$x^{(k)}=\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i^{(k)}$$

and

$$y^{(k)}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i^{(k)}y_i^{(k)}}{x^{(k)}} .$$

Now, interpreting your question. You're interested in the change in the overall average between year $1$ and year $2$, i.e. the value of $y^{(2)}-y^{(1)}$. You say that $y^{(2)}-y^{(1)}=10$. You want to write this as a sum of ten independent statistics, the first five depending on $(x_i^{(2)}-x_i^{(1)})$ for $i$ from $1$ to $5$ (i.e. the five changes in population sizes) and the other five depending on $(y_i^{(2)}-y_i^{(1)})$ for $i$ from $1$ to $5$ (i.e. the five changes in average height).

Unfortunately this isn't possible. Thinking about it intuitively: if the average height of a group goes up between year $1$ and year $2$ then how much this affects the overall average depends on how large the group is. If the group is large then the change in average height for this group will have a larger effect on the overall average height. The influence on the overall average of a change in the average height of a group cannot be unpicked from the size of that group.

We can play with it a little to get:

$$\begin{align}
y^{(2)}-y^{(1)} 
&= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i^{(2)}y_i^{(2)}}{x^{(2)}} - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i^{(1)}y_i^{(1)}}{x^{(1)}}
\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^5 \left( \frac{x_i^{(2)}y_i^{(2)}}{x^{(2)}} - \frac{x_i^{(1)}y_i^{(1)}}{x^{(1)}} \right)
\end{align}$$

So if you calculate the value:

$$\frac{x_i^{(2)}y_i^{(2)}}{x^{(2)}} - \frac{x_i^{(1)}y_i^{(1)}}{x^{(1)}}$$

for each of your groups (for $i$ from $1$ to $5$) then the sum of the values will equal $y^{(2)}-y^{(1)}$ ($=10$) and each of the values gives you, in some sense, the "influence" on the overall average of the corresponding group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciate it. If you consider the volume to be a population split (out of a total 100%) does this make it any more possible? I would really like to try to quantify whether it is the change in population size / split or the change in average height of the group that has driven the overall change.

Comment: I also think (please correct me if I'm wrong) that the first answer may fall down when you are looking at zero or negligible values. Take this extreme  example:        <br>        $y_1^1$ = 0.01, $y_1^2$ = 0.01, $x_1^1$ = 100, $x_1^2$ = 1000       <br>        $y_2^1$ = 2, $y_2^2$ = 2.1, $x_2^1$ = 100, $x_2^2$ = 100        <br>        $y^1$=1.005, $y^2$=0.2<br>Using your formula above, this would assign a value of 0.004 to group 1 in terms of influence, and -0.809 to group 2, from a total $y^2$-$y^1$ of -0.805.

Comment: I think it is clear here that group 1 has the larger influence by multiplying its population by 10, but almost all of the influence has been assigned to group 2, which has not really changed?

Comment: Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Your example is good. I've played around with it a bit more, but sorry, I've nothing else for you yet.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate you trying to look at it